# Python how do I add user entry to a new value on a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple Tkinter entry.

When a user inputs an entry and presses the button on the GUI, I want it to add the user entry to a list named `self.players`.

This works to an extent. The entry is added to the list but when I type in a second entry and press the button it replaces the first entry on the list instead of adding it onto the list as a second entry like I want.

How would I make it so the entry is added to a new value each time.
Thanks

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        self.welcomeLabel = tkinter.Label(text = "Welcome to Darts!")
        self.welcomeLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.playerLabel = tkinter.Label(text = ("Type in Player names!"))
        self.playerLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.playerEntry = tkinter.Entry()
        self.playerEntry.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.playGameButton = tkinter.Button(text = "Play", command = self.game_button)
        self.playGameButton.grid(row=4, column=0)


    def game_button(self):
        self.players = []

        playerData = self.playerEntry.get()

        self.players = (playerData)

        print (self.players)

myApp = Application()
myApp.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append`:

```
self.players.append(playerData)
```

**Your current code simply overwrites the data already stored in the list with the new information.**

That's why the information in the list is only the most current entry. `append` adds it to the information already in the list.

REFERENCE

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html